# Put div in drop up

Tags: html, css

I have a div in my footer that I would like to put inside a drop-up.
I tried this but it wont put the div inside the button. I found it here
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu-dropup&stacked=h

this is what its doing
https://jsfiddle.net/tmfmtocf/
Does anyone know how to do this?
My footer...

```
    <footer id="chat">
        <div class="dropup">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropup Example
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="boxContainer">
                <h2 style="color:red;">Chat</h2>
                <div id="scrollBox" style="height:100px;width:100%;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
                    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="message" />
                <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
                <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
            </div>
       </div>
</footer>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What are you referring to as a drop-up?

Comment: I want this http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_dropdown-menu-dropup&stacked=h but with the div instead of a list. I tried modifying the code in the example but it wasnt working.

Comment: @ShaeLaRie StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. You need to do the work yourself and then come back with a specific problem you're having. Then, we'll help you solve it.

Comment: @WesFoster I edited it to what I've been trying.

Comment: @ShaeLaRie Great, thanks! Try putting together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com), or include screenshots, so we get a better idea of the behavior. Also, try to provide an example of what it *should* look like (perhaps from another website, or screenshot)

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Please include that in the question itself, not on a third-party site...

Comment: I cant find an example of it, but in the fiddle you can see what its doing right now. I appreciate the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have bootstrap loaded on your page then you just need to add the class of `dropdown-menu` to your `boxContainer` like so:

```
    <footer id="chat">
        <div class="dropup">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Dropup Example
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="boxContainer dropdown-menu">
                <h2 style="color:red;">Chat</h2>
                <div id="scrollBox" style="height:100px;width:100%;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">
                    <ul id="discussion"></ul>
                </div>
                <input type="text" id="message" />
                <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
                <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
            </div>
       </div>
</footer>
```

Fiddle Demo [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/5umo0j4b/)

Comment: It is showing but since your div is at the top of the page you can't see it because the menu is droppnng up above.  I revised your fiddle whith the footer on the bottom.

Comment: No problem glad to help